# Issue with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

In my page I have some styling, then a form, then some java-script code.

I have two issues:

**First:** when I click button **'submit'**, all my styling goes away, also the expected action (div to appear) does not happen.

**Second:** I have an output-text for displaying a small phrase saying subscription was successful or not, which reads a bean property called result. The problem is that this property never gets refreshed. The inputFields after I refresh the page they come up clean, this outputText no. How can I make it get without any text when user comes to the page for the second time?

Thank you so much!

**Style:**

```
#mainTableRightDiv1 {
    display: none;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

**Body:**

```
<button class="button" id="subscribe">Subscribe</button>

<div id="mainTableRightDiv1">

    <table class="hidden" id="formTable">
        <tr>
            <td id="formTd">First Name:</td>
            <td><h:inputText class="form" id="inputFirstName" value="#{visitor.firstName}"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="formTd">Last Name:</td>
            <td><h:inputText class="form" id="inputLastName" value="#{visitor.lastName}"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="formTd">Email:</td>
            <td><h:inputText class="form" id="inputEmail" value="#{visitor.email}"/></td> 
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

<p><h:commandButton class="button" id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{visitor.registerVisitor()}"/></p>

<p><h:outputText class="output" id="result" value="#{visitor.result}"/></p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
   $("#subscribe").click(function (e) {
    $("#mainTableRightDiv1").css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried: `$("#mainTableRightDiv1").show()` to make the div appear?

Comment: Clicking functionality is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/obw89aLu/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your jquery statement with the .on() event instead of .click(),also make sure that you have included jQuery.

As for your second question, you can set the result to no text when the document has been compiled with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    result = "";

    $(document).on("click","#subscribe",function(){
        $("#mainTableRightDiv1").css("display","block");
    })
});
```

It is recommended to put all of your jquery code in the $(document).ready() function to ensure that everything executes.